# Ref param returning array of unknown size. How to handle?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, com, ref

A COM component exposes an API which expects a ref param of object type. As per the documentation of this API, it will fill the ref object with array of values. Now my problem is in prod env I can't predict the number of elements which I will get back.

Following code will work.

```
     COMClass objCOM = new COMClass ();
     object colOfInts= new int[10]; // What if I don't know the following will return array of size 10?
     int errorcode = objCOM.FillThisIn(ref colOfInts);
```

But what if I don't know the size of array that API returns in ref.

Update here

```
        object colOfInts = null;
        int errorcode = objCOM .FillThisIn(ref colOfInts);
```

now when I check the type I get System.Int32[*]

Basically I need to iterate through this array and check for the presence of an element

Comment: is the COM side expecting a SAFEARRAY or just a standard int[]?

Comment: If the API is going to fill the values into your structure, it must have a way to let you know what is the structure's expected size. If the memory is allocated on the API side, you don't need to care at all.

Comment: Why would you need to allocate memory on your side of the code if the array is returned from inside the API call?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield the COM is expecting an object type not an array

Comment: Perhaps paste in the relevent section in the API doco here so we can help you better?

Comment: @tcarvin FillThisIn(pcolOfInts As Variant) As Long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting back an array whose lower bound isn't 0.  That's not uncommon in COM interop, the next likely choice is 1.  You don't have to copy it, you can access the elements with Array.GetValue().  Array.GetLowerBound() tells you where to start, Array.GetLength() or Array.GetUpperBound() tells you how far to go.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got some solution on this . Forgot to mention erroCode will have the size of the array.

```
        int[] test = new int[errorCode];            
        Buffer.BlockCopy((System.Array)colOfInts, 0, test, 0, errorCode * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting back an array of `System.Int32`, you probably just need to cast:

```
    object colOfInts = null; 
    int errorcode = objCOM .FillThisIn(ref colOfInts); 

    int[] arrayOfInts = (int[]) colOfInts;
```

Then `arrayOfInts.Length` will have the number of elements in the array.

Comment: No, you can't cast an int[*] to an int[].

Comment: @HansPassant, exactly I was unable to cast Int[*] to Int[]