# Something similar to UBound in C#

Tags: c#

In my efforts to learn C#, I've been writen code for a small project in both Vb and C#.  I've made progress, but ran into a problem trying to implement something which was easy in Vb.  This routine reads a results file from a chromatography system.  The problem happens when I try to determine the size of the arrays of the processed peaks which vary in size depending on the integration limits of the various peaks.  My goal is to stuff them into lists which will then used to display the peaks on a XY plot. I've searched and there are two options typically offered, but they didn't work for me, but maybe there is something else that I'm missing.  I've tried to use the GetUpperBounds property

```
nPoints = mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j).GetUpperBound(0);
```

and referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic and using something like

```
nPoints = Information.UBounds(mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j);
```

In either case, I get an error like "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[*]'to type 'System.Double[]'".  Which would make sense if I was trying to create the array, instead of determining its size.

The code is shown below.  I had problems pasting the entire class.  What's missing are the namespace, using statements, class def and then the first method which displays a dialog to get the file name to read.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks, Ray

```
    private void readFile(string file)
    {
        PLCirrusResults  myRstFile = new PLCirrusResults();

        myRstFile.Load(file);
        IPLCirrusRstSampleInfo mySampleInfo ;
        IPLCirrusRstSliceTable mySliceTable ;
        IPLCirrusRstProcessedPeaks myProcessedPeaks;

        mySampleInfo = (IPLCirrusRstSampleInfo)myRstFile;
        mySliceTable = (IPLCirrusRstSliceTable)myRstFile;
        myProcessedPeaks = (IPLCirrusRstProcessedPeaks)myRstFile;

        // read the sample info header
        string sampleName = mySampleInfo.SampleName.ToString();
        double conc = Convert.ToDouble(mySampleInfo.Concentration);
        double injVol = Convert.ToDouble(mySampleInfo.InjectionVolume);

        // read Slice Table
        int nPeaks = Convert.ToInt32(mySliceTable.NumberOfSliceTablePeaks);
        int nPoints = 0;

        IList<double> rTs = new List<double>();
        List<double> sConcs = new List<double>();
        List<double> normHts = new List<double>();
        List<double> responses = new List<double>();

        for (int j = 1; j <= nPeaks; j++) 
        {
            nPoints = mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j).GetUpperBound(0);
            for (int i = 1; i <= nPoints; i++) 
            {
                rTs.Add(mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j)(i));
                responses.Add(mySliceTable.get_ResponsesAt(j)(i));
                normHts.Add(mySliceTable.get_NormalisedHeightsAt(j)(i));
                sConcs.Add(mySliceTable.get_ConcentrationsAt(j)(i));
            }
        }
        string msg = String.Format("The sample is: {0}", sampleName);
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "file Info");
        }
    }
```

Added:  sorry for the delay, it's a long story.

Stack Trace:

```
[External Code] 
ElastGPCAnalysis.exe!GPC.Model.CirrusFiles.readFile(string file)` Line 71 -> this is the line with the GetUpperBounds(0);
ElasttGPCAnalysis.exe!GPC.Models.CirrusFiles.openFile()` Line 38
ElastGPC.exe!GPC.GPCViewModel.btnLoadSample()` Line 34

[External Code]
```

then calls to Caliburn.micro follow.

To answer the question asked about how get_RTsAt is defined.  Again pasting a screen shot would be easier, but I can't yet.  So I'll type what I can.

The dll I'm referencing is called PCLGRAMLib.dll and IPLCirrusRstSliceTable in one of the many interfaces available.
   dynamic get_RTsAt(int Peak)
    Member of PLCGRAMLib.IPLCirrusRstSliceTable comes from Object Browser.

Comment: How is `IPLCirrusRstSampleInfo.get_RTsAt()` defined?

Comment: Any reason why `.Length - 1` doesn't suffice?

Comment: Please post a simple piece of code that actually exhibits the problem. Throw out irrelevant code, but include enough to reproduce the problem. For example this is missing the essential `IPLCirrusRstSampleInfo.get_RTsAt()` definition.

Comment: Hard to explain how GetUpperBound could fail.  More about non-conforming arrays in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227314/ref-param-returning-array-of-unknown-size-how-to-handle)

Comment: @Ray_B123456 Looking at your update, it looks to me that the line that's failing is `myRstFile.Load(file);` and that has nothing to do with `GetUpperBound(0);`. What made you believe so?

Comment: No, line 71 corresponds with the line of code where GetUpperBound was used.  I was able use Alexander Morou's suggestion below to cast the object as an array to get around the problem.  Getting to the point of reading the arrays wasn't as simple as it was in Vb, but with some workarounds it did work.  Thanks for your help.  I'll continue work with what I have, but I'm hoping that the software vendor has a newer version of the their SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the declaration of get_RTsAt?

C# supports exporting metadata for types which are vector-arrays if single-dimensioned; however, if you have an array which is non-zero by design you might run into issues.

If you are the author of the library which denotes the get_RTsAt, then try making its result type Array, versus a non-zero array type.

The vectorized design of arrays (which by definition are arrays that are guaranteed to be zero-indexed if single-dimensioned, or SD) is there are Common Intermediate Language opcodes which optimize access to such arrays, which provides incentive for using zero-based, or vector, arrays.

If my hunch is correct the issue you're running into is C# is trying to parse the metadata but it fails to do so.  C# will **never** export a type which is a non-zero single-dimensioned array, and in my tests in writing a compiler I ran into issues trying to interop with SD non-zero arrays.  The clue to this is the error you are receiving, the: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[*]'to type 'System.Double[]'`  The '*' is your hint, and shows you what to look out for.

**Edit**- Since you don't have access to the original source, try the following:
Could you try to cast the results of get_RTsAt to Array via:

```
var rts_at = (Array)(Object)mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j);
nPoints = rts_at.GetUpperBounds(0);
```

And tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the author of the Library, which dates from ~2000.  I've asked the vendor if there was a new version of the SDK, but haven't gotten a response yet.  But from what I know, in the Vb code, the arrays are not zero based.

Comment: I've edited the answer to have you try something simple, I have to write MSIL to check it so that'll come here in a few minutes.

Comment: Drats, for the life of me I can't recall how I encountered errors like this a few years ago.  It appears as if you explicitly declare the types as non-vector arrays in IL and compile the library you get something C# won't even interop with.  Which makes me wonder: are you interfacing with a COM library?

Comment: Yes, I am interfacing with a COM library.  But your suggestion to cast the Object as an array did work. After that I was able to use the GetUpperBounds to obtain the size of the arrays. But I had to do the same for all of the arrays to get the data into the lists.  Is there something which would make working with a COM library easier?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not off hand, since you're performing interop with COM, and that COM library is exporting something that isn't expressed in the actual COM interfaces you're given, you're at a bit of an impasse. The only suggestion I might have is to reverse engineer(RE) the Type Library and manually patch it up to use an Array type, versus the incorrectly typed typestrict version of the array they provide. Though that's probably going to come with some Gotchas. The best thing you can hope is your vendor responds.  I'm glad casting it to an array worked for now, though. --Edit on the RE: Check your EULA first.

Comment: One suggestion you might try is: on the block of information you want to work with, you might try creating a type which represents a given set of data you want to work a lot with.  It would take a little bit of memory, but you could perform a [constrained copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.constrainedcopy) over the data sets you want into a type which specifies the zero-based array copies.  Work with that data, and do a few unit tests on performance to see if it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `Length` or `Count` in cases like this. So for example, I would use the following in your code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < mySliceTable.get_RTsAt(j).Length; i++)
```

Remember that in this case you need to change the `<=` to just `<` for obvious reason.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that I had tried using .Length with the same error.

Comment: @Ray_B123456 Well, the problem is not with your use of `GetUpperBound()`. Which line is giving you the error? Perhaps you can post the stack trace.

Comment: I would paste screen snip, but I don't have enough points to do so.  So I'll type it out quickly

Comment: @Ray_B123456 Just edit your question and paste it there.